# Add text reflection to UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uitextfield, mirror

I am developing an app in which there is a requirement in which there is a text in text view. I have to give mirror effect to that text view text. I am searching on Google but can't find any solution.

How  can I solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried to rotate text view.but logically its not right.Actually,I want to give mirror effect to text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a [blog post](http://saveme-dot-txt.blogspot.com/2011/06/dynamic-view-reflection-using.html) awhile ago that uses a view's CAReplicatorLayer. It's designed for handling dynamics updates to a view with reflection.  The post uses a UIWebView, but you could just use a UITextView instead.

Answer (score 2):

Add a [`UILabel`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html) right beneath the text field. Apply a scale [transformation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) to mirror it. Scale the y axis by -1 and the x axis by 1. Then all you have to do is update the text in the label every time the text field changes.

Comment: Please explain a little bit more.I can't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [Demo project](http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/08/no-fuss-reflections/). It has what you want.

Comment: Link is outdated.